# Proving that this function is continuous based on definitions of two sets

Tags: functions, continuity

**Question:** Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) > d\}$ and $\{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x) < d\}$ are both open sets for all real values of $d$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

**My idea:** For a function to be continuous, the limits of all values in the domain must converge. We can perhaps write the function's range as $f(x) \in \mathbb{R} / \{d\}$ and prove that the function is somehow continuous here. I'm not sure if this is even correct, but I'm not sure how else to approach this problem. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have written the same set twice. i think one needs to be $<d$ and one needs to be $>d$

Comment: Sorry about that, it's all fixed now

Comment: You only have to look at the inverse images of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the (countable) union of open intervals. Now, the two sets you have mentioned can be written as $f^{-1} \left( d, \infty \right)$ and $f^{-1} \left( -\infty, d \right)$. Can you form all possible open intervals using the intervals $\left( -\infty, d_1 \right)$ and $\left( d_2, \infty \right)$? If you can, you are through, since unions and intersections behave well under pre-images.

Comment: What is your definition of a continuous function? If you have enough topological tools in your back pocket, this follows from general nonsense because the hypothesis is that the inverse image is open for all elements of a subbase. But if you have to use delta-epsilon then there is a lot of unpacking left to do. (Edit: some of the unpacking was done in Aniruddha's comment :P)

Comment: I'd say that a function is continuous at a point $x_0$ such that $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists and equals $f(x_0)$. A continuous function means that the function is continuous at all points in the domain.

Comment: you mention open sets in your problem statement. Are you familiar with continuity defined in terms of open sets?

Comment: @CSquared No, I am not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are going to show that $f$ is continuous, according to the epsilon-delta definition of continuity. Note that for $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, for $r>0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, we denote $$B_{r}(\mathbf{x})=\{\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n:||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||<r\}$$

Fix $\mathbf{x}_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. The sets
$$A=\{\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(\mathbf{y})<f(\mathbf{x}_0)+\varepsilon\}\text{ and }B=\{\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(\mathbf{y})>f(\mathbf{x}_0)-\varepsilon\}$$
are both open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $x_0\in A\cap B$, then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $B_{\delta}(\mathbf{x_0})\subseteq A\cap B$ (this is because $A$ and $B$ are open sets). Now, for any $\mathbf{x}\in B_{\delta}(\mathbf{x_0})$, we have $$f(\mathbf{x}_0)-\varepsilon<f(\mathbf{x})<f(\mathbf{x_0})+\varepsilon$$ which implies $$|f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{x_0})|<\varepsilon$$hence $f$ is continuous.

If you are familiar with continuity in terms of open sets, then this proof gets shortened as follows:

The collections of all intervals $(-\infty,d)$ and $(d,\infty)$ for all real values of $d$ forms a subbase for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Since every open subset of the reals is a union of finite intersections of these basis elements, it follows that $f$ is continuous.